Amazon Cognito Logout problem Required String parameter 'redirect_uri' is not present
I can run my logout URL directly.
domain/logout?client_id={clientId}&logout_uri=https://localhost:7098/

However, when I give this link as a href to the button on the website and the button is clicked, I get the error "Required String parameter 'redirect_uri' is not present".
I have added Allowed callback URLs an Allowed sign-out URLs.

Have you tested the url formated? The issue is more like a frontend issue. Also The /logout endpoint only supports HTTPS GET, please check if it is meeted.

This is the error you get if the logout URL does not exactly match a logout URL in the allowed sign-out URLs.
I suspect you have https://localhost:7098 as your allowed sign-out URL (without the trailing slash).
Adjusting to domain/logout?client_id={clientId}&logout_uri=https://localhost:7098 should do the trick.
Good luck with your project.
